# Eclipse IDE don't import static Mockito method

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, junit

I write simple test, where is mockito static method like verify, times, any.
And problem next, i can not import this method automatically or click to method and chose Import,
i can only write in the top of my class import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify; or  import static org.mockito.Mockito.test;
[image]

Comment: In the preferences _Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites_ add `org.mockito.Mockito.*`.

Comment: i choose in favorites > org.mockito.Mockito.* and then > Apply> Apply and Close, but nothing to change, sorry.   Then i delete import static, click on method and everything repeat  "create method" offer to me my IDEA ECLIPSE

Comment: It will not provided via Quick Fix (Ctrl+1), but via Content Assist (Ctrl+Space). So place your cursor behind `times` and hit Ctrl+Space.

Comment: i use Cltr+Space, choose necessary method in List, and this is work with import, tnx)